# Objective-c filling array with characters range from "A" to "Я"

Tags: objective-c, arrays, loops, pointers, char

This code sets names of all elements as "Я" instead of range from "А" to "Я":

```
for(int i=0; i<NEURONS_COUNT; i++) {
    char sym = (char)(128+i);
    NSString* name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", &sym];
    name = [name substringToIndex:MIN(1, [name length])];
    neurons[i] = [[Neuron alloc] init];
    [neurons[i] setName:name];
}
for(int i=0; i<NEURONS_COUNT; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [neurons[i] getName]);
}
```

Why? How can I fill names with values from "A" to "Я"

Comment: what is the implementation of `[neurons setName:]` , is it default one synthesized, or you did override it?

Comment: Yes, it was overridden. Just made the property and synthesize. The problem was solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do create `name` string incorrectly. You do pass a pointer to char to string format specifier which is not NULL terminated, thats why do do some magic with substringToIndex..

You should change your lines

```
char sym = (char)(128+i);
NSString* name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", &sym];
name = [name substringToIndex:MIN(1, [name length])];
```

to

```
unichar sym = (0x0410+i);
NSString* name = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&sym length:1];
```

Comment: If I use "%c" it entails problems with charset. I got '?' instead of letters. But if I use format "%s" I got letter but with '\0' in the end, substring is needed to delete '\0'.

Comment: It seems you are trying to get cyrillic alphabet, I've updated the answer